# complex String matching

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, string-comparison, string-matching

In Java, I'm using Levenshtein algorithm (apache commons) to try to match a list of say object to another "almost polished" list. The almost polished contains things like:

- Bread
- Screwdriver
- Screw
- Tomato
- Book
- Tomato juice
- Half apple
- Green Apple
- Apple

The other big list can contains the same words as above but also something else, since it can be part of a sentence or just a specific item (eg. a quarter of a green apple or an used book about programming). The item on this list are indexed and belong to a specific Box. It's a database table where the items are indexed.

What I'm trying to do is to link the big list of items with the "polished" list. like

- A quarter of a green apple => apple
- A slightly used programming book => book (or programming book if it's on the list)

Levenshtein could have been the solution, but I don't get what I expect, sometimes is totally wrong, sometimes it's not intelligent enough ( "programming keyboard" is indexed with "programming book" and not "keyboard" ).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I thought my first step is to clean the polished list, but I don't know how to do that yet. Maybe I should weight the words on the list as well (if there are more than one word, "-ing" words are less important, for example)

I also suspect I should give several level of matching. 100% match,80% etc.

Comment: why levenstein? if you do not have problems with spelling but only want to identify said words, then you could just perhaps try to make an easy String.contains(word) ?

Comment: I can have spelling problems since both lists comes from the user. The ordered is way shorter though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two problems. First of all you have a sentence from which you need to find a keyword (book f.e.). Here you have a problem if you are having a sentence like "spooky parasol" where spooky has Levenstein-distance 4 from book.

After you have retreived the keywords from sentences, you can of course compare each word with the specific item-words and consider the miss-spelled word to be the item-word of the shortest levenstein-distance. The problem is that for each word you need to make a levenstein-comparison with each item.

The finding of keywords is easier if you know what your items may be. If you don't have a specific set of items but all proper nouns will do, then you really have a problem ;)

Comment: The finding of keywords means that I should have a list of keywords..which is basically what I want to do. I can restrict the set (food, office items maybe 99% correct), but then what I need to do is a list of items, to check that my list of items is correct and then use it to get the item from the sentences. Redundant, but maybe I can solve the problem : apple -> half apple -> a sliced half apple.